# How to set a min value for a thumb in RangeSlider in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, rangeslider

I want to have a range sldier that shows for example the values 0 to 24, but of which the lower thumb is bound to a minimum value depending on the hour of the day (such that it cannot be set in the past).

I looked through the [RangeSlider docs](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html) and the [Slider docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html), but cannot seem to find a property that suits my needs. Any ideas in how I can set the min value of a range slider other than the `setMin()` method? When this method is used, it completely discards the values in the slider lower than the set minimum which I want to avoid.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I coudn't find a way to do it, so I haven't really tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

let your range be called in the FXML file like this:

```
 <RangeSlider fx:id="rangeSlider" blockIncrement="20.0" 
       highValue="50.0" lowValue="10.0" min="0.0" max="59.0"
       minorTickCount="50" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="821.0" 
       showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" 
       snapToTicks="true" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" />
```

and it the controller inject this rangeSlider as well

```
@FXML
private RangeSlider rangeSlider;
```

then use the methods `adjustLowValue` and `adjustHighValue` to set the values you want

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    ...
    rangeSlider.adjustLowValue(10);
    rangeSlider.adjustHighValue(50);
}
```

hoping this help some way